# android publishing: app not compatible with many devices

Tags: android, gps, compatibility, google-play

I am publishing a GPS based app for API 11+.I tested and developed it mainly on an ASUS TF201(the notorious prime) and some HTC and samsung phones. In the publish page-> device compatibility it shows that my app is not compatible with the TF201, while being compatible with TF300, TF700 and TF201. Now from my experience, these devices have all pretty much the same hardware and software, why is TF201, TF300TG and TF101g excluded? Could it be because the TF201 had GPS removed from its specs list shortly after launch?(alum. body->no GPS) It can still be used with a bluetooth antena, so why exclude? Also, TF300TG does have functioning GPS so why the incompatibility? I am writing google about this, meanwhile I want to know if anyone else encountered it

Answer (score 0):

Google determines if your application is compatible with devices based on your `Android Manifest`. GPS requires permission. Now your `Android Manifest` doesn't specify that you need either `bluetooth or GPS`, the Google server assumes you need both for the application to work. The server actually makes sure ALL the conditions in the manifest file are satisfied. Hence the TF201 is included in the incompatible list.

Comment: So you think requesting permission to use bluetooth should fix it? Im not sure about that because usually that is done by a third party bluetooth gps provider that uses Mock Locations to provide a system wide LocationSource, there are very few GPS apps that have built in bluetooth GPS support. How come I can see other GPS apps from the tf201? I will try and read their manifest. And by the way, it does have an internal GPS antenna, it does try to get a signal but it fails everytime.

Comment: If you can see other apps requesting permission to use GPS on the tf201 it's probably some other permission or criteria that your app requires that the tf201 doesn't meet. Perhaps screen size? Did you specify anything like that? Could you paste the link to your app?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sl.kestrelgps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zbC5rZXN0cmVsZ3BzIl0.

Comment: As I said earlier, the TF300 or TF700 run the same sw/hw as the TF201, there is really no difference between them, except the fact that TF201 never gets a GPS signal because of the alum. body. Apart from that, the device meets all the other requirements for almost any android app, but now it makes me think how many play sotre app's are not visible from the TF201